# Extending program without altering the source code. SOLID PHP OOP

Tags: php, solid-principles

Let's say we have few elements:

1) **Simple PHP Class**

```
<?php 
  class page {
    function display() {
      // Display widgets implementing widget interface
    }
 }
?>
```

2) **Interface for Widget Classes**

```
<?php 
  interface Widget {
    function print();
  }
?>
```

3) **And few classes implementing the Widget interface**

```
<?php
  class Poll implements Widget {
    function print() {
      echo "I'm a poll";
    }
  }

 class Form implements Widget {
   function print() {
     echo "I'm a form";
   }
 } 
?>
```

What is the right way taking in mind SOLID PHP OOP logic to automatically run print() function in all classes implementing Widget interface? Let's assume all the files are already included.

Basically, whenever new class implementing Widget is created, it's response should be printed out in a page.

Maybe all my logic behind this is wrong?

Comment: Accept a `Widget` in your `page`'s constructor and run `print()`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with accept a widget, please? I'm self taught and not really good with programmer's language.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you clearly, you want to use a `Widget` in your `page` class right?

Comment: @Mehdi I would like `display()` method in `page` class run `print` method in all classes that implement `Widget` interface without specifying each one like: `$a = new Form; $a->print();`

Comment: Do you mean that `Page::display()` should not pick widgets from a list but rather print all object instances of classes that implement the `Widget` interface?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes, you're right. Basically, script `$page = new Page; $page->display();` should echo `I'm a poll I'm a form`

Comment: And I would like this to be easy scalable, so whenever I create a new class implementing `widget` I won't need to modify `Page::display()` to print it's response.

Comment: You still need to create instances of the widgets (`$foo = new Poll()`, etc.). Should that be automated as well?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I would prefer to have this automated. Anyway, I'm not sure if it's a good practice. But picture it might be if for example during the time program would scale to dozens of classes implementing `Widget`. This is for educational purposes, I just want to realize the best way to deal with situations like this.

Comment: @A.Zemgulis are you storing the created widgets in a place? like a database or a config file? that would be easier.

Comment: @Mehdi no, while building my application for learning purposes I came to the place where I needed to efficiently integrate the widgets. I'm aware of database or config file option. Just wanted to know if PHP offers any way of extending programs without touching any files built before. I understand that this is probably too much complexity for a simple thing, but just wanted find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of without using any config or database is to get all declared classes and check the ones that implement the `Widget` interface:

This is the modified `Page` class

```
class Page {

    public $widgets = [];

    public function addWidget(Widget $widget)
    {
        $this->widgets[] = $widget;
    }

    public function display()
    {
        // Now you have an array of Widgets you can loop through them
        // And run print()
        foreach ($this->widgets as $widget) {
            $widget->print();
        }
    }
}
```

And then we can get all classes (that are loaded) that implement the `Widget` interface:

```
$widgets = array_filter(
    get_declared_classes(),
    function ($className) {
        return in_array('Widget', class_implements($className));
    }
);
```

And then we pass them to `Page`:

```
$page = new Page();
foreach ($widgets as $item) {
    $widget = new $item;
    $page->addWidget($widget);
}

// Now Page has all Widgets we can call display()
$page->display();
```

But be aware that `get_declared_classes()` will return a lot of classes (160 in my PC), so we are looping through them all and checking if each one implements the `Widget` interface.

Now whenever you have a class that implements the `Widget` interface it will be used by `Page`. To be honest I don't know if there is a better way so it might be worth it to wait for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a little bit of magic.

Let's say you have all widgets in one directory. You can fetch them with some filesystem operations, iterate over the results, verify whether it is an instance of Widet, create new instance and run it.

This solution has one big benefit. You write this code once and each new widget will be automatically included and run. This solves the open close principle :)

But it also has some cons:

- you have to use filesystem,
- IDE will does not know that the Widget implementation are used,
- it is harder to understand.

Another solution is to have a class like WidgetCollection which will know all the widget in the system and it can provide you them. So when you will create a new widget implementation you will have to add it to the collection, that's all :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really say if it adheres to SOLID principles but I can think of two approaches:

1. Store widgets in a directory and use [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading. Then use file system functions to scan the directory and create instances of class names that correspond to file names. (Make sure you have full control on directory contents or you'll be hacked!)

   ```
   // Totally untested code with no error checking
   foreach (glob(YOUR_BASE_DIR_HERE . '/Widget/*.php') as $file) {
       $className = 'Widget\\' . basename($file, '.php');
       $widget = new $className();
       $widget->print();
   }
   ```

   This assumes that widgets do not need to be configured thus instance creation can be automated.
2. Tweak the widget spec so that each file returns a properly initialised instance and `include` it (same warnings apply):

   ```
   foreach (glob(YOUR_WIDGETS_DIR_HERE . '/*.php') as $file) {
       $widget = include $file;
       $widget->print();
   }
   ```

   … where every included file ends with something like `return new Poll();`.

   It's important that included files do not pollute the global scope with variables. Depending on how complex widgets are expected to be, you may want to have actual class definitions elsewhere so you adhere to [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) coding standard: *Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.)
   or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.)
   but SHOULD NOT do both.*